# Printing pdf file in webview

Tags: swift, xcode, printing, webview

I want to add a print `Button` into my app to print local `pdf` files.

So I added a `UIToolBar + UIBarButtonItem` and linked it with my following code:

```
@IBAction func printButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared

    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)

    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfo.OutputType.general

    printInfo.jobName = (wkWebView.url?.absoluteString)!

    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfo.Duplex.none

    printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfo.Orientation.portrait

    printController.printPageRenderer = nil

    printController.printingItems = nil

    printController.printingItem = wkWebView.url!

    printController.printInfo = printInfo

   // printController.showsPageRange = true

    printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true


    printController.presentFromBarButtonItem(printButton, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)

}
```

On the last line I get this error message:

> Cannot convert value of type '(Any) -> ()' to expected argument type
>   'UIBarButtonItem'

I tried different ways but I'm stuck. It would be awesome if someone can help me. I think it's easy to solve but not at the moment for me.

Comment: what is printButton? it should be of time UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: It's my print button in the toolbar. Also my identifier name + label & the func name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are required to pass the argument as bar button. But you are passing sender, which is "Any" at the moment.. either use a guard to downcast it as bar button like

```
 guard let barButton = sender as? UIBarButtonItem else {
            print("not bar button")
            return
        }
 printController.presentFromBarButtonItem(barButton, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

Or change the sender to

```
IBAction func printButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)

 printController.presentFromBarButtonItem(sender, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove action than try to addAction with sender

```
IBAction func printButton(_ sender: Any) //instead  of
IBAction func printButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
```

Comment: Which swift version are you using ? I tried your code at 4.2 and no error encountered.

Comment: I've forgotten to change 'printButton' to 'sender'